# ForkJoin is running on 1 thread

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join

I have the following code, which is a simulation of a sort of site scraper, which scrapes pages/ subpages and joins the result to a string with the contents of the pages.

I have used `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`, so I assumed that it will run on multiple threads. But this does not seem to be the case.

```java
package Concurrency;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;

public class ForkJoinPoolDemo {

    public static class MyTask extends RecursiveTask<String>
    {
        private String url;
        public MyTask(String url)
        {
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        protected String compute() {

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "/" + url);

            if(url.equals("http://google.com/b1")) {
                return "Content from /b1";
            } else if(url.equals("http://google.com/b2")) {
                return "Content from /b2";
            } else if(url.equals("http://google.com/b")) {
                List<MyTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
                tasks.add(new MyTask("http://google.com/b1"));
                tasks.add(new MyTask("http://google.com/b2"));
                String result = "Content from /b\n";

                for(MyTask task : tasks) {
                    task.fork();
                    result += task.join() + "\n";
                }
                return result;
            } else if(url.equals("http://google.com")) {

                List<MyTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
                tasks.add(new MyTask("http://google.com/a"));
                tasks.add(new MyTask("http://google.com/b"));
                tasks.add(new MyTask("http://google.com/c"));
                tasks.add(new MyTask("http://google.com/d"));
                tasks.add(new MyTask("http://google.com/e"));
                tasks.add(new MyTask("http://google.com/f"));
                tasks.add(new MyTask("http://google.com/g"));
                tasks.add(new MyTask("http://google.com/h"));
                tasks.add(new MyTask("http://google.com/i"));
                tasks.add(new MyTask("http://google.com/j"));
                String result = "Content from /\n";

                for (MyTask task : tasks) {
                    task.fork();
                    result += task.join() + "\n";
                }
                return result;
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "Content from " + url;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        String result = pool.invoke(new MyTask("http://google.com"));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Why is every fork running on the same thread?

```
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19/http://google.com
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19/http://google.com/a
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19/http://google.com/b
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19/http://google.com/b1
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19/http://google.com/b2
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19/http://google.com/c
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19/http://google.com/d
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19/http://google.com/e
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19/http://google.com/f
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19/http://google.com/g
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19/http://google.com/h
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19/http://google.com/i
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-19/http://google.com/j
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're blocking on join each time you spawn a new task waiting for it to complete before submitting another task. Instead, spawn all the tasks first and then collect their results:

```
for(MyTask task : tasks) {
  task.fork();
}
        
for(MyTask task : tasks) {
  result += task.join() + "\n";
}
```